# How do I Draw a Chessboard using XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, chess

I am working on a project that requires me to develop an application using the Universal Windows Platform (UWP). I have no prior knowledge of developing UWP apps and XAML is completely new to me. Thankfully however, I am competent at writing in C#.

The project I am working on involves recreating the Tafl Board games - Hnefatafl, Brandubh, Tablut, etc.

Now, while I'm fairly confident in my ability to create the underlying logic for the game, I find myself bamboozled when it comes to creating the interface using XAML.

Several different chessboards will need to be rendered: 7x7, 9x9 and 11x11.

So my question is two-fold.

1. How do I create a chessboard in XAML that will scale appropriately to different window/display sizes and be able to be backed by a grid behind the scenes (i.e. The application can detect which square of the board is touched, etc)
2. How do I go about rendering a different board depending on the game type selected?

Apologies if this is a terrible question but googling hasn't helped me a whole lot and StackOverflow has always been a great source of information.

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921077.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You can use the built in editor to do quite a bit. If you can get your hands on Microsoft Expression Studio, you can accomplish it with an even more powerful UI.

Comment: you start by doing some research on your own.. this is not a code factory site.. also what have you done as well as tried on your own.. and if your requirement is to develop something then you need to do some research ..

Comment: Step 1: try _something_. I have found personally that when learning a new environment, it is rarely fruitful to dive in with a complete-formed problem to solve. This will be especially important in the context of UWP/XAML/WPF/etc. That said, maybe you should look at the `UniformGrid` class, to start with (assuming it's present in UWP...not sure if it is; if not, you can use `Grid` with explicit formatting).

Comment: @PeterDuniho The UniformGird is not present in UWP and I'm not quite sure how I can use the Grid to generate chessboards that will resize correctly based on different sizes. Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury of dipping my toes in the pool in regards to UWP and XAML. They're requirements for my final year project. :(

Comment: @MethodMan I've done some research of my own and I've found nothing that pertains to answering my question. The documentation is verbose,so getting through it to find what I need, when I'm not quite sure what it is I need is going to be a lengthy and mostly fruitless search. I am not asking for ready-made solutions, I'm asking for direction.

Comment: There are at least two mechanisms I can think of to get `Grid` to work the way you want: use `Width="*"` for your column definitions and the equivalent for row definitions so that the grid layout actually adjusts as desired as the object changes size; or declare the grid using fixed dimensions and then put it inside a `Viewbox` element configured to scale the entire grid accordingly as needed. In either case, you'll need to narrow your question considerably before it's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for the suggestions, I'll look into the Viewbox and see if that will work for me. Once I've done some experimentation, I'll see if I can narrow down my question a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try out the [RelativePanel](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-017-XAML-Layout-with-RelativePanel) control and use different coloured [rectangles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) for the tiles. This would resize for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you finally got an answer to this that led you in the right direction.  If you didn't here are some ideas that might narrow your research terms and get your going.  I'd give you working samples but youd did mention it is for a school project :).

1. Using a listbox and manupulating the base style can be a relatively
   good way to go, and very reusable.  This also fulfills your
   requirement of knowing the tile currently selected as the listbox
   already handles that.  I used this technique for a Sudoku board that
   had alternating colors for the different regions.
2. Create a UserControl with properties for the number of columns and
   rows you need for your board and then dynamically add the rows and
   columns to the grid.  If your game model has a list of tiles and
   each tile has a column and row property that can be mapped to the
   column and row indices of the grid, you could potentially bind to it
   quite easily.
3. Create a custom control that handles the columns,
   rows and other aspects of the board itself in c# and the rendering
   in XAML.  I personally shy away from this just because the existing
   controls are already so flexible that with enough ingenuity you can
   create what you need with out of the box controls.